# Groovy Regular matching everything between quotes

Tags: regex, groovy

I have this regex

```
regex = ~/\"([^"]*)\"/
```

so Im looking for all text between quotes
now i have the following string

```
options = 'a:2:{s:10:"Print Type";s:8:"New Book";s:8:"Template";s:9:"See Notes";}'
```

however doing

```
regex.matcher(options).matches() => false
```

should this not be true, and shouldn't I have 4 groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matcher()` method tries to match the entire string with the regex which fails.

See [this tutorial](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions) for more info.

I don't know Groovy, but it looks like the following should work:

```
def mymatch = 'a:2:{s:10:"Print Type";s:8:"New Book";s:8:"Template";s:9:"See Notes";}' =~ /"([^"]*)"/
```

Now `mymatch.each { println it[1] }` should print all the matches.

Comment: `mymatch.each { println it[1] }` prints just the matches :-)